# Angular Material Grid List Lazy Loading

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lazy-loading, angular-material

I have created a grid page using angular Material Grid list. Is there way to integrate the Material "Virtual Repeat" (Lazy Loading on scroll) with grid list? So basically loading more grids on scroll.

Any help or demo would be appreciated

Answer (score -1):

This example has Virtual Repeat done for drop-down list. Am sure its similar for a grid as well.

```
<md-virtual-repeat-container id="vertical-container">
    <div md-virtual-repeat="item in ctrl.filterDS" class="repeated-item-vertical" ng-click="ctrl.toggleSelection(item.name,item.id)" flex>
        <input type="checkbox" value="{{item.name}}" ng-checked="item.selected">{{item.indent}} {{item.name}}
    </div>
</md-virtual-repeat-container>
```

Refer: http://jsfiddle.net/VBharath/n1r6hwcg/22/